# Can you publish multiple self-contained .NET 6 projects with one shared set of libraries?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I have read somewhere that one could *"[...]create an empty project with references on your two applications and publish the newly created project."*, but that answer was years old, and the other answer said it's not possible.

Does that work, to just create an empty project that references the rest of the assemblies or is there maybe some kind of different method now?